# JavaScript Scope of Variables and Frames

Tags: javascript, scope, frames

I got different javascript-Files and a website with frames. In generalJavascript.js I wrote this

```
console.log("BP0 - generalJavaScript.js eingebungen;");
top.window.clickedNewForm = false; 
function setClickedNewForm(booleanobj){
    console.log("BP5 - setClickedNewForm(); top.window.clickedNewForm: " + top.window.clickedNewForm + ";");
    top.window.clickedNewForm = booleanobj;
    console.log("BP6 - top.window.clickedNewForm: " + top.window.clickedNewForm + ";");
}
function getClickedNewForm(){
    console.log("BP7 - getClickedNewForm();");
    return top.window.clickedNewForm;
}
```

In Firefox-Console I can see messages like this:

```
Permission denied to access property 'clickedNewForm'
generalJavaScript.js()genera...ript.js (Zeile 11)
[Bei diesem Fehler anhalten]    
top.window.clickedNewForm = false;
```

What is wrong ? I thought if I declared a global var on top-object it will be accessable from all frames?!

UPDATE: tried to use parent.myvar instead of top.window, unfortunately nothing changed, FF-Console:

```
BP0 - generalJavaScript.js eingebungen;
genera...ript.js (Zeile 10)
Permission denied to access property 'clickedNewForm'
generalJavaScript.js()genera...ript.js (Zeile 12)
[Bei diesem Fehler anhalten]    
parent.clickedNewForm = false;
```

Comment: Are your frames all served from the same domain (exactly the same domain, including protocol)? If not the browser's same-origin-policy will prevent access to the variables.

Comment: Yes it seems that SOP is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the parent object to access value's from a parent frame.

```
console.log("BP0 - generalJavaScript.js eingebungen;");
parent.clickedNewForm = false; 
function setClickedNewForm(booleanobj){
    console.log("BP5 - setClickedNewForm(); parent.clickedNewForm: " + parent.clickedNewForm + ";");
    parent.clickedNewForm = booleanobj;
    console.log("BP6 - parent.clickedNewForm: " + parent.clickedNewForm + ";");
}
function getClickedNewForm(){
    console.log("BP7 - getClickedNewForm();");
    return parent.clickedNewForm;
}
```

Comment: Still the same ... see Update.



genera...ript.js (Zeile 12)
BP0 - generalJavaScript.js eingebungen;

Comment: Well, make sure you're not cross domain scripting I would say. I use these accessors all the time for posting binary forms and recieving back when it's processed to the parent frame. That would fail if you're using crossdomain(eg myscripts.domain.com accessed from domain.com will fail)